# Getting vlookup result of multiple row and multiple column

Tags: microsoft-excel

As title, I am stuck where I would like to get all the result for name "A" with formula.

Below is all the value that has been given. However, I would like to get just the name "A".

[image: Capture1]

and below is the result that I would like to have.

[image: Capture2]

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Try `=FILTER()`

Comment: @I'-'I  I need it to work in excel..

Comment: Excel is offtopic here.

Answer (score 0):

**`=QUERY( A1:D17; "select A, B, C, D where A = 'A'"; 1)`** **~> ~> ~> ~> ~>** **`(EUROPE SYNTAX)`**
**`=QUERY( A1:D17, "select A, B, C, D where A = 'A'", 1)`** **~> ~> ~> ~> ~>** **`(U.S.A. SYNTAX)`**

[image]

Comment: I tried and it did not work

Comment: @D.D cant be. maybe you need comma version: **`=QUERY( A1:D17, "select A, B, C, D where A = 'A'", 1)`**

Comment: @user0 i think this will not work in excel

Comment: @D.D this site is about web applications, not desktop programs. this answer is for Google's Spreadsheet - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bhR4H8SX_RwpRo5S41CkG3ALOSxd9z-z12LjcF4uAGg/edit#gid=2000840577